# Basic question on spin wavefunction

Tags: quantum-spin, standard-model, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, baryons

In my textbook, I am told that the $\Delta$ is a spin-3/2 particle made up of three spin-1/2 quarks. For a state with definite spin $m=-1/2$, I'm given that the spin wavefunction $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow +\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow+\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow)$$
This seems wrong to me since the quarks are fermions and must have anti-symmetric wavefunction. What is wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1):

First, your understanding is right and this is a problem, which caused the introduction of colour charge. The overall wavefunction has to be antisymmetric and therefore we have to introduce another "degree of freedom" which can be described by a wavefunction too: The colour wavefunction, which can be antisymmetric, and therefore cause the overall wavefunction to be antisymmetric again.